# merge two variables having arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable `$first` which is an array.
Another variable `$second` is also an array with different data.
`$first` is assigned to `$data['result']`.

Now I want to merge `$second` with `$data['result']`.

Comment: try array_merge() and merge $first and $second then assign the merged arraty to $data['result']

Comment: fixed code formating and grammer

Comment: Thanks to both of you ,array_merge worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `$data['result'] = array_merge($first,$second);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this example and see if it works:

```
$data['result']=[$first,$second];
```